# Съедает текст у границ страниц при печати

Tags: css

Добрый день.

Почему при печати съедает часть текста в районе границ разрыва страниц?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Границы страницы прописаны через css правило

```
@page {
    size: A4;
    margin: 1cm;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что печатаешь table из хрома (или аналогичного браузера).

Текст не съедается, эта одна строка разрезана горизонтально на 2 части, причём хром это делает намеренно, если текст находится внутри таблицы. Хорошо заметно, если сделать печать в pdf и попробовать скопировать текст - одна и та же строка (разрезанная) повторится дважды (как нижняя строка первой страницы и верхняя следующей).

Могу лишь предположить, что разработчики хрома так поступили, с целью сделать возможной печать таблиц с последующим склеиванием листов, хотя сомнительно, чтобы принтеры смогли это распечатать вообще без полей.

Некоторое время назад пытался решить такую же проблему (правда, там ситуация была немного другой), но не вышло. Хотя, стоит попробовать применить где-нибудь css-правила, связанные с page-break (возможно, придётся обернуть содержимое ячейки в дополнительный контейнер), но не знаю, поможет ли.

Comment: Да, так и есть, картинка печати как раз из Хрома ... править содержимое ячеек и таблицы не могу, содержимое подгружается из внешнего источника и должно быть "как есть" ...

Comment: @Unknown, странно, не получается воспроизвести проблему, но я точно помню, что с ней сталкивался раньше. Версия браузера последняя? Попробуй добавить `tr, td { page-break-inside: avoid; }` в стили.

Comment: @Qwerty, последняя - 42.0.2311.135 m. Добавление правила не помогло ...

Answer (score 1):

> Почему при печати съедает часть текста в районе границ разрыва
>   страниц?

запретите разрыв страницы внутри этого элемента

```css
tr {
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]